# What is the keycode for search/next/send button

Tags: android, mobile, android-softkeyboard

does anyone know what keycode I have to press for this Send/Search/Next button?
I'm trying to send a chat message and can't find a solution to this one.
Already tried keycode: 66 and 84.

[keyboard view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qf7BN.png)

Comment: Can you please explain more about your question? Like what you want? You want to show send icon or anything else?

Comment: I need to automate action to type a message and send a message by pressing "Send/Done" button on an android soft keyboard. I can't find a keycode for this action. As a workaround solution, I'm using tapping on an element by it's coordinates. I already tried different key events https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/view/KeyEvent.java but none of them work for me. I have native mobile app and I can see thats it's Gboard virtual keyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For adding action on click of send/done button of soft keyboard, Need to add `setOnEditorActionListener` to edittext.

`EditText` code in xml :

```
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:imeOptions="actionSend"
            android:singleLine="true"/>
```

In Java class:

```
    editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEND) {
                String text = editText.getText().toString();
                Log.e(TAG,"text-----"+text);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

You can add any `imeOptions` to edittext according to your requirement.

For more info related to **EditerInfo** [check official doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/EditorInfo).

Comment: Thank you! Are there any alternative methods to test it in javascript?